# VoIP push failed, `Notification error: APN invalid token` in Production

Tags: ios, voip, pusher

I tried to send VoIP push.
I could send by using Sandbox environment. But, I couldn't send by using Production environment.

Why can't I send ?
I build my app by release mode (AdHoc iOS 13).
I checked voip capability.

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: I succeeded to send by using Sandbox environment. But production environment failed.

Comment: You have to add your developer keys to work on live.

Comment: @KamalPanhwar What is the developer keys ? Where should I add it to?

Comment: They can be get from Apple developer programmer, you will p12 or p8 keys

Comment: @KamalPanhwar My p12 file was imported to pusher, you can check in the first image. I could send in sandbox environment but couldn't send in production it.

Comment: not sure about your situation, I used fcm_push gem and it was giving me same issue, when I was using development version it was doing fine, but on production it was giving me error, but it was about IOS app and its permission settings, also some changes done with p12 files. Another issue was what I am sending in JSON, it require few more parameters to work but you already sending in sandbox so hope it would be not issue. I have no clue how to solve it.

Comment: @KamalPanhwar Does it means VoIP ? In apple developer site, there are one selection for VoIP.

Comment: I am sending it using ruby on rails `fcm = FCM.new` where my body of message is `  options = { "notification": {
        "title": title,
        "body": body,
        "msg_action": action,
        "msg_type": type,
      },
                  "badge": 1,
                  "alert": "dasdas",
                  "sound": "default" }
` and then `fcm.send(registration_ids, options)` registration_id is token receive on mobile app. just sharing may be it will help you, but I am using FCM and fcm_gem, but when app is running chances it won't show, but when app not running notification will

Comment: I have exact the same issue, the token value doesn't change if I switch between production and development in my app. I expect a different token when switching to Production (Release), but the token keeps the same. I'm quite sure I use a different certificate. Did you find a solution?